# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 6

Tags: php

My php code is

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = "";
$user_pass = "";
$mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and 
Password '$user_pass';"
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "login success";
}
else{
echo "login not success";
}
?>
```

error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 6

Comment: Semi colon missing, You need a good IDE

Comment: `and Password '$user_pass';"` You're forgetting something here. and I don't mean the semi colon

Comment: WHERE SEMI COLON IS MISSING ?

Comment: At the end of the query $mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and 
Password '$user_pass';"

Comment: also query is not correct

Comment: I AM NOT GETTING CAN YOU ?

Comment: CapsLock broken?

Comment: There is no ; at the end of `$mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and Password '$user_pass';"`.  Note that writing everything in CAPS LOCK means you are shouting. This is considered rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's nothing.. you just misplaced semicolon.

just change this

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and 
Password '$user_pass';"
```

to this.

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and 
Password '$user_pass'";
```

Comment: How would this then be interpreted by the query? `and Password '$user_pass'"`

Comment: we don't need to do semicolon while passing query in variable. it just becomes value of variable. so syntex should be like variable.

Comment: You do realize this is an invalid syntax `like '$user_name' and Password '$user_pass'`. There's nothing between the column and variable

Comment: yes i know this is wrong syntex, he has written wrong sql query and also wrong php syntex. so i just gave him the right php syntex.

Answer (score 3):

you have misplaced the semicolon, add semicolon at the end of the query and use '=' after password

```
$mysql_qry = "select * from logindetails where User_id like '$user_name' and 
Password = '$user_pass'";
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain what was missing in OPs code.